# Bootstrap carousel - How to make a external link to a specific slide

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

maybe I´m not using the right words as I´m totally new to bootstrap, but I´m not being able to do this... I have a html document with this code:

```
<div class="item" id="screen_1_1">
          <h2>1. Title</h2>
          <h3>Definition</h3>
          <p>content</p>
    </div>
<div class="item" id="screen_1_2">
          <h2>2. Title</h2>
          <h3>Definition</h3>
          <p>content</p>
    </div>
```

So, I wanted to ask, how can I link from another website, to this website and open it directly, for example, seeing the second slide? Is this possible?

Comment: your question is not clear :( are you talk in about carousel ? http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

Comment: "how can I link from another website, to this website and open it directly, for example, seeing the second slide? Is this possible?" You'll have to develop this part. Complicated to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<!-- first slide -->
<div class="item" id="screen_1_1">
      <h2>1. Title</h2>
      <h3>Definition</h3>
      <p>content</p>
</div>

<!-- second slide -->
<div class="item" id="screen_1_2" onClick="javascript:location.href='http://www.google.it/'">
      <h2>2. Title</h2>
      <h3>Definition</h3>
      <p>content</p>
</div>
```